# How to send Authorization API Key via add to = Query Params?

Tags: vue.js, axios

how to send this Authorization Header via Vuejs?

[image: my api key]

Comment: Did you try reading the Axios docs, if that's the client you're using?

Comment: Yes i tried axios
        .get(
          SETTINGS.AUTH_BASE_PATH, { headers: 'My Key apiKey', 'my-api-token' }
        )
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response)
        })

Comment: Including that header? What happened? Give a [mcve].

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at ' from origin 'http://vue.test' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: And what makes you think that's related to the auth header? Have you read up on CORS? You need to address this on the *server*, not the client.

Comment: because i tried first to create the get call in PHP. there i have no problems. my response in vue is an 403, which means the API Key and User Agent is missing. I try to adopt this call in vue but it doesn't work. in postman i also get an 403 if i miss the Auth Header

Comment: Postman doesn't do CORS validation. This isn't a 403.

Comment: ok i have no idea what you mean.. do you have a link ?